# Javascript or jQuery: Is there a way to set document.referrer without changing it every time a page reloads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to send a user back to the URL they came from after looking at a map gallery I'm building. document.referrer would work perfectly except that there are links within my gallery that change the initial document.referrer URL. Is there a way to set document.referrer once, on the initially entry, without it changing each time a new URL is loaded?

Comment: No, and i'd expect you to run into issues when you come across someone who has that header disabled.

Comment: I believe document.referrer is read-only, but you can save the initial value to localStorage and read it from there later.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store it somewhere on their first visit. In a cookie or localstorage, if you're restricted to client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

If the url is unknown that you want to reach you want to use javascript's `history.go(-lengthofitemsingallery)`
If you know the url that you are sending them and that is where they came from then you want to use `history.go("Url")`
If they haven't gone there yet the you want to do a javascript redirect by opening a new window that opens in self like so:


    myWindow=window.open('URLTOPAGE','_self','')

```
You could also do
    LocalStorage['Home'] = document.URL
    //end of gallery:
    document.location=LocalStorage['Home']
```